# How to install Privoxy on Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, privoxy

https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/installation.html#INSTALLATION-PACK-WIN

> Just double-click the installer, which will guide you through the
>   installation process. You will find the configuration files in the
>   same directory as you installed Privoxy in.
>
> Version 3.0.5 beta introduced full Windows service functionality. On
>   Windows only, the Privoxy program has two new command line arguments
>   to install and uninstall Privoxy as a service.
>
> Arguments:
>
> ```
> --install[:service_name]
>
> --uninstall[:service_name]
> ```
>
> After invoking Privoxy with --install, you will need to bring up the
>   Windows service console to assign the user you want Privoxy to run
>   under, and whether or not you want it to run whenever the system
>   starts. You can start the Windows services console with the following
>   command: services.msc. If you do not take the manual step of modifying
>   Privoxy's service settings, it will not start. Note too that you will
>   need to give Privoxy a user account that actually exists, or it will
>   not be permitted to write to its log and configuration files.

I have installed Privoxy to `~\Program Files (x86)\Privoxy`. I opened an administrator command prompt in that location, but when I run `--install`, I get the following error:

```
'--install' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Can someone provide step-by-step instructions?

Comment: Can you provide the full command your attempting to use

Comment: You need to provide the name of the program not just the arguments. Presumably something like `privoxy --install`

Comment: @DavidPostill: Privoxy service is now installed, but I can't start the service: http://i.imgur.com/KKjYk2V.png  
I have set Privoxy to start automatically, but don't know how to "assign the user you want Privoxy to run under".

Comment: Do what it says and look in the system event log for the error.

Comment: Please [edit] the question instead of putting updates in comments.

Comment: Follow the instructions you have already included in the question.

Comment: Right click the service > Properties > Log on > Set the user here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved with a help of [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill) (question comments section).

1. Open an administrator command prompt. Run `cd [Privoxy install location]`, for me the correct command is `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Privoxy`. Now run `privoxy --install`.
2. Go to Services (services.msc). Find Privoxy service `Privoxy (privoxy)`  and set startup type to automatic (`right click > properties > general`).

   - Configure Privoxy to use your user account be selecting `this account` in `properties > log on`. Press `browse`, type your username to the `enter the object name to select` field and your account should be found after pressing `check names`. Click `OK`.

[image]
[image]

Comment: `log on` tab only appears on service.msc (not on process hacker)

Comment: @JinSnow: I'm not familiar with Process Hacker, please edit the answer if beneficial.